# jQuery accordion-like menu with animate height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a bit of an issue with a toggle effect I am trying to set up (almost like an accordion menu) but with it animating the height. The issue is, that since click toggle was deprecated, I have an issue that if you open a menu, then close that menu, and open another... it works fine... but if you open a menu, then click another without closing, you have to click ti twice to reset the false/true variable set.

I have included my code (simplified) below, and a JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/qtuwwhpz/

I'm wanting it to be as 'accordion' like as possible... the menus animate open and close regardless if one is open or not.

```
var subMenuClicked = false;
$('.each-dropdown-container h3').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!subMenuClicked) { // First click
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var el = $(this).next('.reveal');
        var curHeight = el.height();
        var autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
        el.height(curHeight).animate({
            height: autoHeight
        }, 500); //
        subMenuClicked = true;
    } else { // Second click
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next('.reveal').animate({
            height: 0
        }, 500);
        subMenuClicked = false;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is to check if has class active like following:

```
//var subMenuClicked = false; you don't need anymore
$('.each-dropdown-container h3').on('click', function (e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) { //here check if has class active instead of use a bool variable
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var el = $(this).next('.reveal'); //
        var curHeight = el.height(); //
        var autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height(); //
        el.height(curHeight).animate({
            height: autoHeight
        }, 500); //
        //subMenuClicked = true; remove this
    } else { // Second click
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next('.reveal').animate({
            height: 0
        }, 500); //
        //subMenuClicked = false; remove this
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qtuwwhpz/6/)